# How this value use comma in xsl

Tags: xslt

xml file like below I want concat value of name, add1, city, add2 with separated by comma

```
<Details>
<name>abc</name>
<profile>
<address>
<add1>ccc</add1>
<add2>bbb</add2>
<city>CA</city>
</address>
</profile>
</Details>
```

I want Output like below:-

```
abc, ccc, CA, bbb
```

(I mean city will come first before add2 and if any value is blank then it will adjust accordingly)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to output all the text nodes within the **Details** element, you simply iterate over them all using **xsl:for-each** and use the **position()** function to output a comma if the node is not the first one

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="Details">
      <xsl:for-each select="//text()">
         <xsl:if test="position() > 1">
            <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="." />
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, if one of your elements has no text in it, it will not get output or have an extra comma.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="name"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="Details/name"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="add1"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="Details/profile/address/add1"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="add2"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="Details/profile/address/add2"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="city"> 
     <xsl:value-of select="Details/profile/address/city"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:value-of select="concat($name,',',$add1,',',$city,',',$add2)"/><br>
```

It will display the O/P like this `abc, ccc, CA, bbb` if add1 returns `null` then it will display like this `abc, , CA, bbb`

Comment: Thank you for answar but in this case I want output like abc, CA, bbb this is a problem

Answer (score 0):

If you're using XSLT 2.0 you can use the `()` operator to construct a sequence in the order you want and then use the `separator` attribute on `xsl:value-of` to output the whole sequence with commas:

```
<xsl:template match="Details">
  <xsl:value-of select="(name, profile/address/add1, profile/address/city,
      profile/address/add2)" separator=", " />
</xsl:template>
```

If you want to filter out elements with an empty value (e.g. if the document contains `<city/>`) then you can do that with a predicate on the select expression:

```
(name, profile/address/add1, profile/address/city,
      profile/address/add2)[normalize-space()]
```

The predicate removes from the sequence any nodes whose value is empty or consists entirely of whitespace.

Comment: This is working fine but in case when element city value is null in that conditon it give result like abc, CCC, , bbb I want result should be like abc, CCC, bbb (if element city value is null)

Comment: @Raj you can do this using a predicate to filter the node sequence (see edit).